# Missing URL parts with devServer proxy

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli

I've got the following vue.config.js in my Vue project:

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '^/api/': {
                target: 'https://example.com/api/',
                changeOrigin: true,
                logLevel: 'debug'
            },
        }
    }
}
```

So all requests to `/api/*` should be redirected to `https://example.com/api/*`. Unfortunately, the proxy seems to remove parts of the URL coming after `api/`:

```
[HPM] POST /api/api-token-auth/ -> https://example.com/api/
```

What happened to the `api-token-auth/` part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To proxy all requests to `/api` according to the syntax in the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy), create the rule as follows:

```js
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: 'https://example.com',
                changeOrigin: true,
                logLevel: 'debug'
            },
        }
    }
}
```

You shouldn't put the `/api` path again in `target` because everything after and including `/api` from your original route will be appended onto the target.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Sometimes one doesn't spot the obvious...